# Swift Fatal Error with if statement

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and have a small amount of code that I just can't seem to get to work:

```
if Tick1.state == NSOnState {
    Textmain4.stringValue = "Quality Enabled"
}
```

This if statement spits out

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What do I need to do to fix this?

Tick1 is an NSButton and Textmain4 is an NSTextField.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `if` statement. When it hits it, see which is `nil`: `Tick1` or `Textmain4`. It's very obvious that one of them is. Also, learn how to use Swift conventions - class instances use camel-case. :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Tick1` or `Textmain4` is an implicitly unwrapped optional (declared with an `!`, like `let Tick1: UIButton!`), you can still use `?` to safely unwrap the object:

```
if Tick1?.state == NSOnState {
    Textmain4?.stringValue = "Quality Enabled"
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!